# How to defragment/consolidate partially filled sqlite pages in order to reclaim space?

Tags: sqlite

I am designing a little server application with local data store and sqlite3 seems to be the way to manage the persistent data. But I am worried about malicious users who know the internal logic and might trick the server into creating (and subsequent deleting) lots of records, in a way where a few valid records remain in each data page. The database size might explode quite soon.

[Following the documentation of](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) and recommendations like https://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2015/01/06/sqlite-vacuum-and-auto_vacuum/ implies that even auto_vacuum=incremental would not help me in this scenario because it's only effective for released pages, not for used pages with internal gaps (i.e. fragmentation).

Is there a good way to tell sqlite to consolidate such data on-the-fly?

VACUUM operation is not an option due to long-living global DB lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite will merge an almost empty page with neighbors automatically to help reduce fragmentation like you describe.

From [an email from D Richard Hipp](https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg117963.html) on the sqlite mailing list:

> Once a sufficient number of rows are removed from a page, and the free space on that page gets to be a substantial fraction of the total space for the page, then the page is merged with adjacent pages, freeing up a whole page for reuse.  But as doing this reorganization is expensive, it is deferred until a lot of free space accumulates on the page.  (The exact thresholds for when a rebalance occurs are written down some place, but they do not come immediately to my mind, as the whole mechanism *just works* and we haven't touched it in about 15 years.)